# How to start dragging sortable item programmatically

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Here is the situation

I have some items/elements and make them sortable using jQuery UI/sortable.
I am using a handle for initiating the drag.

Now I want to have the handle outside of the item to be dragged.
According to the documentation the handle has to be a descendant of the element to be dragged.

The question is:

Is it possible to have the handle outside of the item? Are there any good workarounds?

One thought is to initiate the dragging programmatically, but I have no idea where to start.

This issue has been raised before in the jQuery UI tracker, but it is unclear what the plans are.
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3022